# Display stored array elements of localstorage on web page

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, html, local-storage

I am able to successfully store the values of `localStorage` and display it in `console.log()`. As, the values are stored in an `array`, so I am not able to display them in my `page` with `document.write`. I want the stored values to be displayed on `page`. Can anybody suggest a way to do it? My code is:

```
// List of all entries
console.log(localStorage.getItem("total"));
// Last entry inserted
console.log(localStorage.getItem("intotal"));

document.write(total + "<br>"); // showing in console.log -> "Uncaught ReferenceError: allEntries is not defined "
document.write(intotal + "<br>"); // showing [object Object]
```

I don't want to display elements as:

```
 for(i=0; i< localStorage.length -1; i++)
```

As, I have many `localStorage key/value` pairs and I don't want to display all `localStorage`. By this I mean, I am also storing other values in different key/pair values, like:

```
 localStorage.setItem("Mymarks", (JSON.stringify(marks)); // where marks is JSON object
 localStorage.getItem("Mymarks");
```

So, if I use the `for` loop, then `Mymarks/marks` key/pair value is also getting displayed on my `page`.

My desired output is same as you can see in `console.log`. Like:

```
[{"name":"john","place":"asn"},"text":"abcd"},{"title":{"name":"john","place":"asn"},"text":"abcd"}] 

  {"name":"john","place":"asn"},"text":"abcd"}
```

Comment: Can you clarify by providing an example of your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, we don't know exactly how you want to display them, but this would be a way:

**EDIT**

```
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(existingEntries) + "</pre>");    
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(entry) + "</pre>");
```

Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Comment: Done. I edited my answer to the new output you want.

Comment: It's because the var `existingEntries` isn't defined in other pages. But the solution is much simpler, just do:
`document.write("<pre>" + localStorage.getItem("allEntries") + "</pre>");`
this will work in any page (in the same domain). The same for `entry`

Comment: I don't know why but in `console.log` in other `page` is displaying the desired output but `document.write` is showing only half array on second time page load onwards. Am confused why. P.S. My `entryTitle` is a big `json` object.

Comment: Got it running without using `<pre>`